# loop through documents in a collection to get fields

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a collection called users in firebase firestore. Each document in the collection users is a user registered in the app. Each document has a field called token_ids. How can I loop through all the documents to get the values in the token_ids field. I am using firebase cloud functions to do so. Here is the code snippet I tried using but it did not work:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require ('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

  //fetch all token ids of users

  const tokenReference = admin.firestore().collection("users");

  const tokenSnapshot  = await tokenReference.get();

  tokenSnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{

    console.log("Token ids are:" + doc.data().token_id);


  });

  });
```

Comment: I don't see full code which you have tried.

Comment: Could you elaborate what is your definition of "not working", what is your expected behaviour, what is your current behaviour and how are you running your script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me a while but finally found the solution to it. Here it is. It is the first solution given by Dhruv Shah but slightly modified :

```
async function fetchAllTTokenIds() {

  const tokenReference = admin.firestore().collection("users");
  
  const tokenSnapshot  = await tokenReference.get();
  const results = [];
  tokenSnapshot.forEach(doc => {

    results.push(doc.data().token_id);

  });

  const tokenIds = await Promise.all(results);

  return console.log("Here =>" +tokenIds);


}
```

Comment: If you found the solution, please consider accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since Firestore operations are asynchronous, you should ideally wrap your code in an async-await block.

For example:

```
async function fetchAllTTokenIds() {

  const tokenReference = admin.firestore().collection("users");
  
  const tokenSnapshot  = await tokenReference.get();
  const results = [];
  // Recommendation: use for-of loops, if you intend to execute asynchronous operations in a loop.
  for(const doc of tokenSnapShot) {
    results.push(doc.data().token_id);
  }
  const tokenIds = await Promise.all(results);
}
```

In this way all the `tokenIds` variable will be populated with an array of `tokenIds`.

Alternatively, you can also make all the asynchronous calls in parallel since they are independent of each other using `Promise.all` ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all))

```
async function fetchAllTTokenIds() {

  const tokenReference = admin.firestore().collection("users");
  
  const tokenSnapshot  = await tokenReference.get();

  const tokenIds = await Promise.all(tokenSnapShot.map(doc => {
    return doc.data()
      .then(data => (data.token_id)) 
  }))
```

In this case, the `tokenIds` variable will contain the array of all the tokenIds.

Comment: I tried the first answer. It gave the following error: Unexpected `await` inside a loop

Comment: This seems like a `lint` error. However, I have updated my answer and removed the await from the loop.

Comment: The second solution gave the following error at the cloud functions logs : TypeError: tokenSnapshot.map is not a function

Comment: after the update, I ran the code but it gave out this error TypeError: tokenSnapshot is not iterable , in the cloud firestore logs.

Answer (score 0):

How the code snippet will be structured depends whether you're using the Firebase Admin SDK, be it as a script ran on your local machine or a `httpsCallable` being called by a client app. For the first case, it is written like this:

In your script `file.js`, after initialising app, write the following code.

```
exports.test_f = async function() {
  try {

    const tokenReference = admin.firestore().collection("users");

    const tokenSnapshot  = await tokenReference.get();

    tokenSnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{

      console.log("Token ids are:" + doc.data().token_id);


    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

exports.test_f();
```

Run this script on your command line using the command `node file.js`, which will print the provided output